# Remove pointed line for readonly attributes

Tags: html, css, cursor, line, readonly

Is possible to remove pointed line from an input element with attribute readonly? On disable the behavior is different because disabled elements cannot receive focus events but readonly can.
 So is possible to remove pointed line from readonly inputs?

check fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/DCjYA/364/

Comment: check print screen:http://s16.postimage.org/ghs4zevxh/pointed.jpg

Comment: dont see any pointed line on windows 7 and ie9. Maybe an OS issue.

Comment: it is visible on ie9 firefox, safari,opera. Only chrome in not displaying that line for readonly attributes.

Comment: @mcmwhfy can you please add an image with a decent resolution. Basically you're saying now: Do you see those 5 pixels in that 20 pixels image, that should be a pointed line.

Comment: Not happening in Chrome(v19), Safari(v5.34) and Opera(v11.60). Post bug on BugZilla(for firefox) and on IE Bug Forum.

Comment: better resolution:  http://s14.postimage.org/fdzqypudt/pointed.png

Comment: Do you mean the carrot / cursor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it this way..

```
Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" value="readonly" readonly onfocus="this.blur();"/>
```

Edit:

you can also do it using jquery, so you dont have to add the code on every input

```
Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" value="readonly" readonly class="readonly"/>

<script>
$(".readonly").focus(function () {
   $(this).blur();
 });
</script>
```

Comment: awesome, but how can I add that from css, I cannot modify in each html pages for all inputs because are to many.

Comment: well, i'm not so sure you can do it with css only... actually we are using a script to remove the focus so it gives you the impression that theres no pointer...

Comment: I already use a jQuery for all inputs from my app, I will try to integrate something on my script to do that.